# How to create an apk of react native expo cli project?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

Is there anyone who can tell me to make an apk in react native expo cli as i am quite new in react native and have no knowledge of making builds in react native. If anyone can help it will be a greate help for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the below steps to create an apk using expo cli

**Install expo CLI**
To check if you have expo CLI install run

```
expo -V
```

you need the eas build tools

```
npm install --global expo-cli eas-cli
```

First requirement for generating the apk file is creating an expo account.
Create an [account here](https://expo.dev/signup)

**Login to expo CLI**

- Open cmd
- Login to expo account using the command :
- `expo login`

By default the eas build tool will give you a playstore build file.

If you want a .apk file you need to create a `eas.json` file and add a buildType as apk

```
 {
  "build": {
    "preview": {
      "android": {
        "buildType": "apk"
      }
    },
    "preview2": {
      "android": {
        "gradleCommand": ":app:assembleRelease"
      }
    },
    "preview3": {
      "developmentClient": true
    },
    "production": {}
  }
}
```

You can check out more about the eas [build tool here](https://docs.expo.dev/build/introduction/).

**Build**

Open cmd in your app directory.

**Run the build command**

```
eas build -p android --profile preview
```

**Download apk**

After the build is complete you can go to the builds section in your expo dashboard and download the apk.

https://expo.dev/accounts/username/projects/projectname/builds/0cecd3ee-41aa-4a5a-9cc7-6f7b3ea6fc52

[image]